# How does one enable --write-mostly with Linux RAID?

Tags: linux, boot, raid-1, mdadm

Unfortunately the `mdadm` and `mdadm.conf` man pages are not quite up to par. I would like to enable the `--write-mostly` flag for my RAID, but neither the man pages nor the internet will tell me how. I am not aware of any place to put default arguments for `mdadm`, nor aware of when it would be launched and by what.

It seems the logical place to add this information is `mdadm.conf`, but the flag is unmentioned in `man mdadm.conf`. Where and how can I enable `--write-mostly`? Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set a device to be write mostly with, for example,

```
echo writemostly > /sys/block/md0/md/dev-sda1/state
```

and clear the write-mostly status with

```
echo -writemostly > /sys/block/md0/md/dev-sda1/state
```

Note that you probably need to be root for this to succeed, and that

```
sudo echo state > /sys/block/md0/md/dev-sda1/state
```

won't work.

If you have other questions about `mdadm` or Linux Software RAID, please post them to

```
linux-raid@vger.kernel.org
```

(you do not need to be subscribed).

The kernel panic bug that you mentioned in your answer is fixed in Linux kernel versions released in Jan 2012 and later – 3.1.10, 3.2.2, and 3.3-rc1. It only affected arrays in which all devices are 'write-mostly'.

Comment: On my system, it looks like the path would instead be`/sys/block/md0/md/dev-sda1/state` (note the additional `/md` between `md0` and `dev-sda1`), but I'm also using an older version.

Comment: I just tried this with both mdadm v2.6.3 and v3.2.3, and typing the command as @NeilBrown originally wrote it produces a "No such file or directory" error. Typing the command as I wrote it in my previous comment works as long as you are logged in as root. I've edited the answer to reflect the correct path.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the writemostly property is not persistent when set using this method. After a reboot, the property disappeared.

Comment: I find it strange how the sysfs input parameter is "writemostly", sysfs state file output is "write_mostly", and mdadm command line parameter is "write-mostly". Why so little consistency here I wonder.

Comment: For those who think there are users besides root, `echo state | sudo tee /sys/block/md0/md/dev-sda1/state` will work.

Answer (score 3):

It's been over a week, so to answer my own question:

Apparently you pass it as a command-line argument to `mdadm` when you create a new RAID array; just take the example in the man page and add `--write-mostly`. The man page says all devices after it will have write-mostly enabled; this is vague language so I can only assume it means the reasonable thing: that it applies to the next argument.

On kernel 3.1 (released Oct 2011), however, trying `--write-mostly` / `--write-behind` triggered a panic in `[something...]scsi.c` during some critical step, and destroyed my RAID array.

Also if you are splitting your array, make sure you know what you're doing. I found that my array had new UUIDs (possibly due to a new major metadata version) and was unsure how to proceed.